# Redis dependencies not resolving hence autowiring seems to be failing

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, redis, pom.xml

Having worked on a production Spring boot project since almost a year, I am still having a tough time resolving dependencies in a Spring boot project.

Redis read/write is working fine for one module in our project. All I am trying to do, is to implement it in another. I followed the working module.

Following is pom of the working module (where the @Component is defined) -

Module 1's pom -

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.someproject.dependencies</groupId>
                <artifactId>someproject-spring-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>someproject-common</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In pom of someproject-spring-dependencies -

```
<redis.clients.jedis.version>2.7.3</redis.clients.jedis.version>
<dependency>
                <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
                <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
                <version>${jedis.version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

And in pom of someproject-common -

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I am not sure which of these jedis definitions actually works.

The pom of module 2 is similar to module 1. However, when I try to do the following, in the @Component annotated class of module 2, I get null against object of Autowired RedisDao object, which seems to be a wrapper implementation around the redis.clients package. Trying to give an idea of the same -

- RedisDAOImpl implements RedisDAO. RedisDAOImpl  has @Autowired RedisTemplate.
- RedisTemplate, another wrapper extends RedisBase. RedisBase implements DisposableBean and has autowired JedisPool, which is within package redis.clients.jedis. RedisTemplate has following call -

  Jedis jedis = this.jedisPool.getResource();
- Jedis is in package redis.clients.jedis.
- jedisPool is of type JedisPool, annotated as autowired.
- JedisPool is in package package redis.clients.jedis.

Following is the code in the component of module 2, for which the auto wiring seems to be failing -

```
import com.citruspay.prepaid.common.cache.settings.RedisDAO;

@Component
public class CachedWithdrawalTxnRepository implements CachedWithdrawalTxnDao {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CachedWithdrawalTxnRepository.class);

    @Autowired RedisDAO redis;

@Override
public void create(String uuid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {
        redis.setex("withdrawal:"+uuid, 300, "true");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The redis object shows null and I get a null pointer exception.
I am not sure how to debug further.

**Update**

Answering @Grinish Nepal -

The parent package is being component scanned in the App.java class which is annotated with @SpringBootApplication -

```
@ComponentScan("com.someproject")
```

The class where I am Autowiring RedisDAO is in package `com.someproject.prepaid.common.cache.redis` 
and RedisDAO is in package package `com.someproject.prepaid.common.cache.settings`.

Comment: is the package where RedisDAO resides being component scanned.??

Comment: Yes, the parent package is being component scanned in the App.java class which is annotated with @SpringBootApplication - @ComponentScan("com.someproject"). The class where I am Autowiring RedisDAO is in package com.someproject.prepaid.common.cache.redis and RedisDAO is in package package com.someproject.prepaid.common.cache.settings.

Comment: Not sure whats happening here looks like a scan problem to me... Just a thought you can try to component scan redis.clients and see what happens.